# ipad standalone web app when enter background running trigger which event?

Tags: ipad, web-applications, safari, ios-standalone-mode

I have a ipad web app running in standalone mode (full screen mode), when the web app enter background trigger which event. I tried "blur" and "unload", it looks not take effect on ipad standalone web app. And when the web resume run in foreground trigger which event. Thanks for your advice.